# Labeling radio Options in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, radio-button, label

This is taking way longer than it should. I have the following . . .

```
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:selectRadio label="Update Existing Contact" value="{!createOrUpdateSite}">

                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Update Existing Contact" ></apex:selectOption>

                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Create New Contact (Replace)"></apex:selectOption>



                </apex:selectRadio>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                                    action="{!checkSelectedValue}" 
                                    reRender="none" />

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And one option should set the 'createOrUpdateSite' string in the controller to 'Update Existing Contact' and the other with the corresponding setting.

That works, as tested with a debug, all is well; the only problem is that I cannot properly label these two options. It is mandatory that these two options are part of the same  section because they need to act as a radio option; ie: mutually exclusive. This is by far the least-impressively documented parts of VF I've encountered thus far haha. So guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `itemLabel` attribute on [apex:selectOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm):

```
<apex:selectRadio label="Update Existing Contact" value="{!createOrUpdateSite}">
  <apex:selectOption
    itemValue="Update Existing Contact"
    itemLabel="Update Existing Contact"
  />
  <apex:selectOption
    itemValue="Create New Contact (Replace)"
    itemLabel="Create New Contact (Replace)"
  />
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Comment: Jeez. Thank you so much! Traversed my way around the internet and found all sorts of variations that weren't compatible with my version, apparently. Thanks a million! Any idea how to get it to inherit the formatting that other labels have? For example, a checkbox field's label as well as this one's label (on the apex:selectRadio) have a certain color and font-weight....whereas the itemLabel is pretty plain...

Comment: I don't know of a way to get it to look exactly like the other labels. Using `<apex:selectOption>` should give it Salesforce's native styles. You can always use the `styleClass` attribute to apply your own CSS, e.g. `<apex:selectOption styleClass="myCustomStyle" />` and then put something like `.myCustomStyle { font-weight: bold }` inline in your page or in a Static Resource.